# Normalized LMS with a posteriori Error and Woodburry's Matrix Inversion

Tags: matrix, proof, lms, inverse

I was going through [this](https://publik.tuwien.ac.at/files/pub-et_9859.pdf) paper and the author mentioned that we can prove the following using the Matrix Inversion Lemma (AKA Woodburry's Matrix Inversion Identity):
 *Using matrix inversion lemma we can show that* 
 $$w(k+1) = w(k) + \mu(k)e_p(k)x(k)$$ 
 and $$e_p(k) = d(k) - x^T(k)w(k+1)$$ 
 where $e_p(k)$ is the *a posteriori error*, is equivalent to the NLMS coefficient update equations $eq.(1)$ and $eq.(2)$ which employs *a priori error* in its update equation. 
 
The way I did it, I did not use the Matrix Inversion Lemma and still proved the equivalence I want to know how to do it with the Matrix Inversion Lemma (which apparently is giving me a hard time).
I would be glad if anyone could help me out here. Even a hint would do.

Comment: Could you share your own solution to this if you still have it?